# NSCollectionView annoying delay before dragging when multiple selection enabled

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nscollectionview

I have a basic Cocoa app with an `NSCollectionView` showing a number of files. The collection view allows selecting multiple items at once.

The problem is that in order to select two or more items to drag them out of the collection view, I have to click and hold for about one second for the drag to begin.

If I click and drag right away, the collection view changes the selection instead (i.e. draws the "selection" rectangle).

It took me a while to figure out that I have to **click and hold before dragging**. I can already see that many users of my app won't figure this out and will complain about dragging not working.

Example: problem exists even in Apple's sample code: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/IconCollection/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004477

Interestingly enough, Finder's "icon view" just works as expected (dragging works without delay). Not sure if its using an `NSCollectionView` underneath, but it seems likely.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you already find a solution?

Comment: No, I did not find a solution...

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around this. All mouse events are overridden in the NSCollectionView. The only thing you have control over is the mouseDown event of the NSView contained in the collection and this will not help with the drag delay.

Comment: I ended up trashing the NSCollectionView and using the excellent (though not complete... you'll need to implement some stuff on your own) open source library by Jonathan Willing https://github.com/jwilling/JNWCollectionView

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite [drag&drop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000069i) method i guess. In apple's website, [drag&drop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000069i) section, theres pretty much information, at least for beginning.